# Rapid prototyping for image processing with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to develop an image processing pipeline in a GUI that allows me to fine-tune parameters by dragging sliders or entering numbers. Afterwards I'd like to export it to Python code.

Google recommends PyFlowOpenCV, but I couldn't get [PyFlow](https://github.com/wonderworks-software/PyFlow) to start, and it seems to be dead.

Any project still alive?